# How do I allow smoothing in externally loaded images?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

In Flash, I can go into the properties of an image in the library and check 'allow smoothing' to enable resampling when the image is scaled or rotated.

How can I achieve the same effect for images loaded dynamically by the SWF from an external URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For AS2

take a look here:
http://www.giordanopiazza.com/blog/flash/allow-smoothing-for-external-images-as2/

For AS3

set bitmap.smoothing = true;

example here http://newsourcemedia.com/blog/smoothing-dynamically-loaded-images-in-as3/

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no simple answer:

At this link http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=89255 some guy called `Flash Gordon` posted quite good class for it, so you have to play with it probably.